# why does find_first_not_of fail when it hits the end of a string?

Tags: c++, string, stl

On the [cppreference.com entry](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_not_of) of `std::string::find_first_not_of` it gives this example of text macro replacement:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string to_search = "Some data with %MACROS to substitute";

    std::cout << "Before: " << to_search << '\n';

    auto pos = std::string::npos;
    while ((pos = to_search.find('%')) != std::string::npos) {
        // Permit uppercase letters, lowercase letters and numbers in macro names
        const auto after = to_search.find_first_not_of("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789", pos + 1);

        // Now to_search[pos] == '%' and to_search[after] == ' ' (after the 'S')

        if(after != std::string::npos)
        to_search.replace(pos, after - pos, "some very nice macros");
    }

    std::cout << "After: " << to_search << '\n';
}
```

This works well, unless the `%MACROS` is at the end of the string (shown below), in which case `find_first_not_of` returns `std::string::npos` and this turns into an infinite loop.

```
std::string to_search = "Some data with %MACROS";
```

Why does this specific block of code totally skip the replacement of %MACROS because it's at the end of the string? Does it not consider \0 as "not of" the set of characters it's given?

Comment: _"`find_first_not_of` returns `std::string::npos` ..."_ Yes, and what's actually wrong with that?

Comment: Nothing wrong with the return value, i'm wondering why this specific block of code would totally skip the replacement of `%MACROS` because it's at the end of the string. Does it not consider `\0` as "not of" the set of characters it's given?

Comment: @galois `'\0'` is not part of the string. `std::string` does not have a null terminator (it uses `std::string::npos` instead).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find_first_not_of()` returns `npos` when it doesn't find a match.  In your case, when the macro is at the end of the string, there are no matching characters, thus `npos`.  To handle that condition, simply replace `npos` with `size()` before performing the replacement.

Try this:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string to_search = "Some data with %MACROS to substitute";
    std::string replace_with = "some very nice macros";
    std::string macro_name;

    std::cout << "Before: " << to_search << '\n';

    std::string::size_type pos = 0;
    while ((pos = to_search.find('%', pos)) != std::string::npos)
    {
        // Permit uppercase letters, lowercase letters and numbers in macro names
        auto after = to_search.find_first_not_of("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789", pos + 1);

        // if no matching chars, set after past the last char...
        if (after == std::string::npos)
            after = to_search.size();

        auto count = after - pos;
        if (count > 1)
        {
            // extract the macro name and replace the macor only if
            // the name actually maps to something worth replacing...

            macro_name = to_search.substr(pos + 1, count - 1);
            if (macro_name == "MACROS")
            {
                // found a macro!
                to_search.replace(pos, count, replace_with);

                // start the next search after the replaced text...
                pos += replace_with.size();

                continue;
            }

            // check for other macros as needed...
        }

        // no matching macro, skip the '%' and search again from the next char...
        ++pos;
    }

    std::cout << "After: " << to_search << '\n';
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/eR3q42)

Comment: thank you, this answers exactly the issue I was having